# Tomcat error, Trouble reading session scope variable

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

The variable i'm trying to pass from JSP to servlet is masession.idemp which have been recovered from session scope.

Passing it to the servlet "/creerticket" through:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idemp" value="${masession.idemp}">
```

This is the "priority" properties to pass to the servlet:

```
 <span class="info">Priorité:</span><br>
 <input type="radio" name="priorite" value="1">Faible<br>
 <input type="radio" name="priorite" value="2">Moyenne<br>
 <input type="radio" name="priorite" value="3">Haute<br>
 <span class="erreur">${erreurs['priorite']}</span>
```

Those are two methods in the servlet

```
CreationTicketForm creationticket = new CreationTicketForm(ticketDao);
Ticket ticket = creationticket.soumettreTicket(request);
```

And the error keeps coming from the method `soumettreTicket(request);`

Have a look:

```
/*error -->*/int idemp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idemp"));
/*error -->*/int priorite = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("priorite"));
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
projet.helpdesk.form.CreationTicketForm.soumettreTicket(CreationTicketForm.java:29)
projet.helpdesk.servlets.CreationTicket.doPost(CreationTicket.java:32)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

The line 29 is the 1st one i tagged "error -->"

Comment: request.getParameter("idemp") is empty.

Comment: Did you look into html page source? I suppose ${masession.idemp} returns empty string, that's why it can't be converted to number.

Comment: i tried it in a test.jsp file that contains only `<p>${masession.idemp}`</p> and it passed me the right employee ID so certainly the variable is'nt empty when in the JSP file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED:

I avoided moving to the parseInt() method directly after collecting the parameter because it generates the problem i quoted above.

example.

```
private int getPriorite(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String pr = request.getParameter("priorite");
    if(!pr.isEmpty())
    {
        int priorite = Integer.parseInt(pr);
        return priorite;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a problem with the getter of `idemp`.
Namely, the name of the getter for `idemp` has to be `getIdemp()` in order for you to be able to get it through expression language (`${masession.idemp}`). 
Try it and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: As i said in the comment above, i could show the `${masession.idemp}`
So the setter and getter are'nt involved in this problem, moreover they are fixed at getIdemp and setIdemp